# mxnet train image-classification models

Tags: python, neural-network, mxnet

Due to no step-by-step guidebook to learn how to use mxnet to train a  image-classification model or raise a model's accuracy which alreadly exist , for example, I have 5 classes iamges and I wanna to train a model which can classify these 5 classes things very well. plus, the mxnet guidebook failed to find the detail. How can I do?is there any github projects?

Answer (score 2):

There are [lots of examples](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/image-classification/README.md) in their repository, examples/image-classification. 
I suggest you follow the readme, try the code and then READ the code of the examples.